# Why Linq Preview for VS2005 doesn't create objects?

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2005

I'm using Linq CTP May 2006 for VS2005 (I have to use it, so please, don't suggest VS2008).
The problem is that it doesn't create objects in proper way. I see several solutions:

1) Use DLinq (Disadvantage: doesn't support Language integrated queries)
2) Use SqlMetal (Disadvantage: the same)

But none of them suites me. So the question is: Why Linq CTP doesn't create objects? What can you suggest to use?

---

TIA, Alex

Comment: "Doesn't create objects in proper way" isn't exactly informative. Please give more information. I do hope this isn't for a production system, btw... the CTP was a CTP, after all - not a release. Oh, and DLINQ certainly *does* support language integrated queries...

Comment: Still curious: Why are you using the CTP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding, the problem was that I used System.Data.Linq instead of System.Data.DLinq